# Como ejecutar sentencia sql que esta almacenada en un string en C#

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo en un string la siguiente cadena SQL para actualizar tablas desde textBox.

```
string actualizar = "update pelicula set nombre_pelicula = " + txtnombre.Text.Trim() + " , web_pelicula = " + txtweb.Text.Trim() + " , descripcion = " + txtdescripcion.Text.Trim() + " , anio = " + txtanio.Text.Trim() + "where id_pelicula = " + txtid.Text.Trim();
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(actualizar, conexion);

                SqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();


                //comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Se actualizo correctamente");
                    conexion.Close();
                }
```

Pero con a la hora de modificar los elementos me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde la linea 84 es:

```
SqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();
```

Tambien cuando reemplazo esta linea por:

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Sigue dando el error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que usar parametros, es una pesima practica concatenar los valores en el string

```
string actualizar = @"update pelicula set nombre_pelicula = @nombrepelicula, web_pelicula = @web, descripcion = @descripcion, anio = @anio
                        where id_pelicula = @id";
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(actualizar, conexion);
comando.Parameters.AddwithValue("@nombrepelicula", txtnombre.Text.Trim());
comando.Parameters.AddwithValue("@web", txtweb.Text.Trim());
comando.Parameters.AddwithValue("@descripcion", txtdescripcion.Text.Trim());
comando.Parameters.AddwithValue("@anio", txtanio.Text.Trim());
comando.Parameters.AddwithValue("@id", txtid.Text.Trim());

comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Ademas es un `update` se usa el `ExecuteNonQuery()` el reader solo aplica al `select`

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte! Es que donde estudio me explicaron de esa manera, ¿Que otra manera o que de manera hubieses hecho ese update?

Answer (score 0):

en los campos de tu tabla que son tipo varchar o nvarchar o texto, al ejecutar el query, debe estar entre comilla sencilla o apostofre ' '.

Todo lo que sea text en tu query debe contener ''.

Intentalo de la siguiente manera:

```
string actualizar = "update pelicula set nombre_pelicula = '" + txtnombre.Text.Trim() + "' , web_pelicula = '" + txtweb.Text.Trim() + "' , descripcion = '" + txtdescripcion.Text.Trim() + "' , anio = " + txtanio.Text.Trim() + "where id_pelicula = " + txtid.Text.Trim();
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(actualizar, conexion);

            SqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();


            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Se actualizo correctamente");
            conexion.Close();
```

Comment: En este caso la aplicación es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

Comment: Concuerdo contigo.